# How to reuse / recycle downloaded JSON data from an AsyncTask on Android without redownloading it

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

**Scenario:** in the onCreate function I'm executing the AsyncTask, and in that class is where I'm pulling my json data. Then, based on a large-scoped variable, I'm decided which view to produce (default is 'all'). When an item in the ActionBar is pressed, the large-scoped variable is set differently, and a new instance of the AsyncTask is being created, there-in producing a different view.

**Goal:** Instead of pulling the json data each time a new view is selected, I want to use the same json data that was originally pulled. New json data can be retrieved when the 'refresh' option is selected, however.

I've tried several methods to solve this but I'm kind of new to Android programming and I haven't been able to get around this. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Some of the code is posted below.

---

** eventual solution [code does not reflect yet]**
I didn't really find the solution I was looking for from peers. As I figured, I didn't need a new library or need to cache my data (though maybe these will be helpful later on), rather what I needed was to re-organize my code. What ended up working for me, was that once I obtained my JSON data from my AsyncTask, I called a function in my MainActivity that then stored the JSON string into a variable.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ....
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            new GetContacts().execute();
        case R.id.action_all:
            view_option = 1;
            new GetContacts().execute();
        case R.id.action_open:
            view_option = 2;
            new GetContacts().execute();
    }
}
...
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String jsonStr = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() { ... }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        ...

        if (view_option.equals(1))
                view_all(jsonStr);
        else if (view_option.equals(2)){
                view_open(jsonStr);
    }

    protected void view_all(String jsonStr){
        // uses json data
        ....
    }

    protected void view_open(String jsonStr){
        // uses json data
        ....
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { ... }
}
```

Comment: hint to search for "cache"

Comment: Caching seems like a good option if I wanted to save the data for offline use, or to retrieve the data at a later date. But I just want to reuse a variable that is otherwise being overwritten (in a sense). I will look into caching further but I think a better solution is just rearranging my functions / variables.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Volley library for this. Starting from good tutorials [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Then, sample code for caching Json, you can refer the following:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(0, mUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            mTextView.setText(response.toString(5));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            mTextView.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {                    
            Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
            if (cacheEntry == null) {
                cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
            }
            final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
            final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
            final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
            cacheEntry.data = response.data;
            cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
            cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
            String headerValue;
            headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
            if (headerValue != null) {
                cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
            }
            headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
            if (headerValue != null) {
                cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
            }
            cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
            final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), cacheEntry);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        super.deliverResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        super.deliverError(error);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }
};

MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Happy coding and goodluck!